# How do I sum distinct values?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+---+------------+
|sid| discounts  | 
+---+------------+
| 1 | 10.00      |
| 2 | 20.00      |
  2 | 20.00      |
+---+------------+
```

I need to get the sum of column discounts but if column sid has the same values just add one row to total not all.

So I need to say 30.00 and not 50.00

I tried something like this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT sid FROM (SELECT SUM(discounts) FROM $table_name)
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(discounts) FROM $table_name WHERE sid IN (SELECT DISTINCT 'sid' FROM $table_name)
```

I am just getting 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query will work if you remove `single quuto betwwen sid`

```
SELECT SUM(discounts) FROM $table_name WHERE sid IN (SELECT DISTINCT sid FROM $table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(discounts) from (select discounts,sid  from $table_name group by sid) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
$sql=mysql_query("select SUM(discounts) from table_name groub by sid");
```

Answer (score 0):

its just simple you can use

```
select SUM(discount) from (SELECT discount FROM  `table_name` group by sid) as discount
```

hope this will works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try following SQL:

```
select 
    sum(t.discount) 
from 
    (select 
        distinct sid, discount 
    from 
        $table_name
    ) t
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ea711/3/0)